# setStatusBarOrientation:animated: not working in iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation, autorotate

I've used this code to force an orientation change back to portrait when the user is finished watching the video (it allows viewing in landscape mode), before popping the video view controller off the navigation controller:

```
//set statusbar to the desired rotation position
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];

//present/dismiss viewcontroller in order to activate rotating.
UIViewController *mVC = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[self presentModalViewController:mVC animated:NO];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];
```

This worked perfectly until `iOS 5.1.1`. I've even tried to use the new present/dismiss methods after reading in another post that those should be used now:

```
[self presentViewController:mVC animated:NO completion:NULL];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NULL];
```

The problem is it doesn't work at all. After I rotated the video viewer to landscape and then pop it, my settings view (table view controller) comes back, but also in landscape mode.

I've even tried the tip from [Here](http://9to5mac.com/2012/06/25/apple-pushes-ios-6-0-update-to-devs/)

"The `setStatusBarOrientation:animated:` method is not deprecated outright. However it now works only if the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method of the topmost full screen view controller returns 0. This puts the responsibility of ensuring that the status bar orientation is consistent into the hands of the caller."

So I've experimented with setting a flag to force `supportedInterfaceOrientations` to `return 0` (before calling the first code block above) but it doesn't work either.

Does anybody have a solution for this? 
Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: Exactly the same issue but like you, I didn't find a solution. Anybody?

Answer (score 17):

`setStatusBarOrientation` method has changed behaviour a bit. According to Apple documentation:

> The setStatusBarOrientation:animated: method is not deprecated
>   outright. It now works only if the supportedInterfaceOrientations
>   method of the top-most full-screen view controller returns 0

Comment: Been looking for this answer for a long time, just stumbled upon this, thanks!

Comment: That's strange because the docs also say "The value returned by this method must not be 0"

Comment: This idea won't work if you actually do want to allow more than one orientation.

Answer (score 2):

Your root view controller should answer false to the method `shouldAutorotate` in order that your app responds to `setStatusBarOrientation:animated`

From Apple Documentation: "if your application has rotatable window content, however, you should not arbitrarily set status-bar orientation using this method"

To understand that, put a breakpoint in the `shouldAutorotate` method and you will see that it is called juste after setting the status bar orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14530123/1901733

The current question is linked with the question from the url above.

The statusBarOrientation is a real problem in ios6.