# Very strange orientation reversal of UIView's frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit

I've created and laid out a UIView - everything looks fine, however while implementing a delegate method, I noticed a very odd frame orientation change.

The frame goes from: {{0, 0,} {1024, 768}} to  {{0, 0}, {768, 1024}} <---- Flipped!

**Update:**

***The problem only occurs when my view controller is presented (aka 'modally') from the current view controller. If the view controller is added directly to my UINavigationController, there's no issues.***

So, when adding a new subview (a custom popover) via the delegate method, the layout goes haywire. But only if the view controller is being presented as follows:

```
- (void)presentPicker
{
    GTPPickerController* pickerViewController = [assembly pickerViewController];
    [pickerViewController setDelegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:pickerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**Question:**

1. Is this a common known problem/mistake wrt 'modal' view controllers?
2. How can I fix this?
3. Could it be related to iOS7? I've done this kind of thing countless times before, and never had an issue.

Comment: Do your app support different orientations ?

Comment: try breaking on setBounds or setTransform?

Comment: @DineshKaushik The supported interface orientations are the two landscapes. . and the view controller is instructed not to auto-rotate.

Comment: @nielsbot, Great suggestion, thanks. Nonetheless it wasn't helpful in this case :(

Comment: maybe you can post a minimal code that shows the issue?

Comment: if you're using auto layout perhaps the bounds of one of your superviews was changed instead?

Comment: @nielsbot - No auto-layout. These are code-based views, starting at CGRectZero, and then settling in as soon as layoutSubviews is called. . . I'm going to strip it down and post a simple project that reproduces the issue. . Meanwhile, I have enough info to work around the problem for now - instead of [self presentViewController I can slide up with my own animation.

Comment: probably reducing to miminal case will show where the issue lies. that's my last resort debugging strategy: reduce until the problem goes away.

Comment: Once I had a similar problem, then a I realized that apps on iPad are launched by default in portrait, You must insure that app is in landscape orientation. Check status bar orientation. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810397/status-bar-is-landscape-but-uiapplication-sharedapplication-statusbarorienta